# How to decode fields of a JSON object into a tuple

Tags: json, elm, decoding

I'm currently learning Elm and I'm stuck at decoding JSON.

I have a structure representing blocks:

```
type alias Properties a =
    { a
        | x : { v : Float, pos : Float }
        , y : { v : Float, pos : Float }
        , size : ( Float, Float )
        , el : Float
    }

type alias Pr =
    { v : Float, pos : Float }

type Block
    = Block BlockType BlockProp


type alias BlockProp =
    Properties { visibility : Int, tb : ( Float, Float ) }


type BlockType
    = Rock
    | Ground
```

And I need to decode blocks saved in JSON:

```
{
    "blocks": [{
            "type": "ground",
            "x": {
                "v": "0.0",
                "pos": "30"
            },
            "y": {
                "v": "0.0",
                "pos": "100.0"
            },
            "sizex": "50.0",
            "sizey": "70.0",
            "el": "1.0",
            "visibility": "1",
            "t": "20.0",
            "b": "30.0"
        },
        {
            "type": "rock",
            "x": {
                "v": "0.0",
                "pos": "30"
            },
            "y": {
                "v": "0.0",
                "pos": "100.0"
            },
            "sizex": "50.0",
            "sizey": "70.0",
            "el": "1.0",
            "visibility": "1",
            "t": "20.0",
            "b": "30.0"
        }
    ]
}
```

Could anyone help me out how to construct a decoder to convert blocks saved in JSON to `type Block`? :)

edit:
I've tried something like this:

```
blockDecoder : Decoder BlockProp
blockDecoder =
    map6 BlockProp
        (field "x"
            (map2 Pr
                (field "v" float)
                (field "pos" float)
            )
        )
        (field "y"
            (map2 Pr
                (field "v" float)
                (field "pos" float)
            )
        )
        (field "size" -- I DON'T KNOW HOW TO CONVERT sizex AND sizey TO TUPLE
        (field "el" float)
        (field "visibility" float)
        (field "tb" -- I DON'T KNOW HOW TO CONVERT t AND b TO TUPLE
```

I have problems converting fields to tuples... Also I don't know how to create a Block with the correct BlockType based on the type field.

Comment: No, we won't just write your code for you. SO is not a code writing service. But if you show us what you have tried yourself and ask about a more specific problem, we'd be happy to help you through it.

Comment: oh ok... I appended my code and specified the problem :)

Comment: Great! That's a very answerable question. Just give me a sec.

Answer (score 3):

You can create tuples pretty much the same way you create records like `Pr` just by replacing the record constructor with the pair construction function [`Tuple.pair`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Tuple#pair):

```
map2 Tuple.pair
    (field "sizex" float)
    (field "sizey" float)
```

Similarly, to get the block type you need to decode `type` as a `String`, then map the result of that using a function that converts `String`s to `BlockType`s:

```
map stringToBlockType (field "type" string)
```